# Is there a way in ATS to convert a closure function into an envless function?

Tags: ats

There are two kinds of functions in `ATS`: `envless functions` and `closure functions`. Converting an `envless function` into a `closure function` is straightforward. Is there a way to convert a `closure function` into an `envless` one?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the sum example [here](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/INT2PROGINATS/HTML/x746.html). In this case: "It is straightforward to make loop an envless function by including n as an argument in addition to the original ones".